# Split Line at Point not working in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, line, splitting

[image]

While i was using the "Split Line at Point" function with two features, both with 80000 point features and 90000 line features each, the finished result wouldnt split on the points. It would split a bit further away from the desired point.

Given the line feature has multiple lines overlapping indicating the multiple "routes", is there any way i could split the line features by point regardless of how many line feature it has beneath?

The picture shows what happens after i split using points. The points are on top/intersecting the line feature.

Comment: Are you sure your line features and your two sets of point features all have the same coordinate system?

Comment: Yes. All feature have the same coordinate system and the points are intersected with the lines. I also tried doing the same function with less features (using one of the routes the line feature has) and still has the same issue.

Comment: I am curious how far is "a bit further away" and is the distance consistent for all points?

Comment: @MapHound I added an image showing what happens after i split using points

Comment: @user8893327 Can you provide the scale that this is noticed and/or an approximate distance?

Comment: @MapHound from the first point to the last one its around 300 meters

Comment: Did you first try with an extract ? You could more easily detect the problem.